# Error in installing module using pip

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, db2, pip, easy-install

I am trying to install ibm_db on my windows7 box but I am getting the below error, I have another 2008 R2 box and had no issue installing on it.

Command:   **C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe ibm_db**

Error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe ibm_db

Searching for ibm-db
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ibm_db/
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/ibm_db/: [SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERI
    FY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may   not be found!
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ibm-db/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/ibm-db/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERI
FY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be fo
und!
Couldn't find index page for 'ibm_db' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAIL
ED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for ibm-db
    error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ibm-db')
C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Command2:  **C:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7.exe install ibm_db**

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7.exe install ibm_db
Collecting ibm-db
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ibm-db (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for ibm-db
C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the issue, My system was passing all the requests through a proxy server and the proxy server had some certificate issues that's why I was getting invalid certificate error.

Removed the proxy server and the issue is resolved.